# Sending signature data in response APDU - Java Card

Tags: digital-signature, smartcard, javacard, apdu, ecdsa

I would like to sign some data (the MESSAGE byte array) on my Java Card and then return the signature in a response APDU. My code works fine (or at least I think it does and it returns 9000) without the line *apdu.sendBytes(BAS, sSignLen)*, but when I uncomment it I get an unknown error (*0xC000002B (Unknown error.)*).

When I try to send other data in a response APDU it works flawlessly.

```
apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(MESSAGE, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, (short) MESSAGE.length);
apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) MESSAGE.length);
```

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong or missing? Thank you!

```
public class TestApplet extends Applet {

    ...

    private final static byte SIGN = (byte) 0x01;

    ...

    private final static byte[] MESSAGE = new byte[] { 'M', 'e', 's', 's', 'a', 'g', 'e' };

    final static short BAS = 0;

    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        if (this.selectingApplet())
            return;

        byte buffer[] = apdu.getBuffer();

        ...

        switch (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
        case SIGN:
            try {
                ECDSAKeyPair = Secp256k1Domain.getKeyPairParameter();
                ECDSAKeyPair.genKeyPair();

                ECDSAPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) ECDSAKeyPair.getPublic();
                ECDSAPrivateKey = (ECPrivateKey) ECDSAKeyPair.getPrivate();

                ECDSASignature = Signature.getInstance(Signature.ALG_ECDSA_SHA, false);

                short signLen = 0;

                byte[] signatureArray = new byte[70];

                ECDSASignature.init(ECDSAPrivateKey, Signature.MODE_SIGN);
                signLen = ECDSASignature.sign(MESSAGE, BAS, (short) MESSAGE.length, signatureArray, BAS);

                apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
                Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(signatureArray, (short) 0, buffer, (short) 0, (short) signatureArray.length);
                apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) signatureArray.length);
            } catch (CryptoException c) {
                short reason = c.getReason();
                ISOException.throwIt((short) ((short) (0x9C00) | reason));
            }

            break;

        ...

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably that `signLen` is larger than the Ne value (incorrectly called `Le` in the JavaCard specifications). You are also abusing the `Le` value to mean `(short) MESSAGE.length` by the way. Ne indicates the maximum number of bytes that are expected to be send back.

Comment: Indeed, I used `Le` instead of `(short) MESSAGE.length`. I updated the code. Thank you! I also thought that the problem had something to do with data sizes. How do I tell the card now that the response (i.e. the signature) will be larger then the Ne value, that is how do I set Ne to be signLen so that I can get the response APDU correctly? @Maarten Bodewes

Comment: You cannot, not without asking the card/your application. But most readers allow Ne to be 256 bytes (Le, the encoding of Ne, should then be `00`). As Ne is the *maximum size* you can always set Le to 00 for any command that expects response data.

Comment: It works now. Before signing I create an array that is my output buffer and after signing I copy its content to the buffer. I don't know though why can't the buffer act as my output buffer for signing. Nevermind.

Comment: That should be possible, but without more code I cannot tell. Glad this worked out for you...